# SSRS report show a value if the line above is hidden

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

This is a odd question (I guess) but there is a formula that I can put into ssrs that will allow me to show a value or specified words if the row above has been hidden?

I'm pretty much self taught with this so struggling to think if it's possible or not.

TIA for any help

Comment: What is the expression used to hide the above row?

Comment: What logic hides or unhides the row?  Why couldn't you use the same logic?  If it is just a user interaction (collapsing a group) then put the value in the group.  Sorry, I may not fully understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Previous` function in order to verify the same expression that hides or not the previous row.

i.e.:

- `.Hidden` property of previous row: `=IIf(Fields!Field1.Value = "hide me", True, False)`
- `.Text` property of actual row: `=IIf(Previous(Fields!Field1.Value)) = "hide me", "the previous row is hidden", "the previous row is not hidden")`